# Nagios pluging don't work but shell script work fine

Tags: php, bash, debian, nagios, nrpe

i want to write a nagio pluging that check if php-fpm version is dead or killed.
I have 3 php version in my pc. 7.0,7.1,7.2.
I want to check if one of them is dead.

I created this script in nagios plugin directory but it doesn't works.

```
#!/bin/bash
STATE_OK=0
STATE_WARNING=1
STATE_CRITICAL=2
STATE_UNKNOWN=3
STATE_DEPENDENT=4

for i in $(/usr/bin/ls /etc/php/)
do
statStop=$(service php$i-fpm status | grep dead | awk '{print $3}')
statKill=$(service php$i-fpm status | grep failed | awk '{print $2}')
if [ "$statStop" = "(dead)" ] || [ "$statKill" = "failed" ];

then
    echo "PHP$i-FPM is down,please start it"
    exit $STATE_CRITICAL
else
    echo "php ok"
    exit $STATE_OK
fi
done
```

I use debian 11.Can anyone help me?
Thanks

This work in shell but not with nagios parameter.

```
#!/bin/bash

for i in $(/usr/bin/ls /etc/php/)
do
statStop=$(service php$i-fpm status | grep dead | awk '{print $3}')
statKill=$(service php$i-fpm status | grep failed | awk '{print $2}')
if [ "$statStop" = "(dead)" ] || [ "$statKill" = "failed" ];

then
    echo "PHP$i-FPM is down,please start it"
    
else
    echo "php ok"
    
fi
``done
```

Comment: paste your script at https://shellcheck.net for validation/recommendation.

Comment: Try run this script as dedicated Nagios user to see if it still works.